# Progress bar showing database progress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, installation

I was wondering, since I'm making a GPT Script, I need an installation system to insert database queries, and create tables.

I know how to do that, but the problem is I want to show the progress of creating files, registering the product to my server, with a progress bar, so the user knows how much longer they'll be waiting.

How can I do this?

Comment: `If you can help me, I'll give you a correct answer !UP!!` WOW! I'm all over it!

Comment: Well, Paul hasn't answered yet, so I might take it with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs server-side, jQuery runs client-side. You would have to call a server-side script repeatedly, either to check the number of rows that have been inserted or tables that have been created, etc...or to tell it to perform another step, updating your progress bar on each call.

Either way is a performance hit, so probably not a good idea.

Comment: It's up to you what is good and what isn't. If you are creating 100 tables and you call the PHP script 100 times, then your progress bar will be updated 1% at a time. If you are creating two tables, your progress bar will be updated 50% at a time. If you're ok with that, then I guess it's good. But keep in mind that the more calls you make to the server-side script, the more of a performance hit you will take.